# unable to find percentage in angularjs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

i have 4 text boxes. qty, unitprice, total  and vat. im able get total price but unable to get vat percentage which is totalsum/100* 5. while putting ng-model to totalprice. its text is not coming.how to get total and form that total 5 percent of total value

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" Text="Qty : " runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQty"  ng-model="qty"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" Text="Unit Price : " runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUnitPrice" ng-model="unitprice"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label7" Text="Total Price : " runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txttotalprice"  Text="{{qty*unitprice}}" ng-model="TotalPrice/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label8" Text="VAT @ 5% : " runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtVatPrice" Text="{{TotalPrice/100 * 5}}" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Try {{(TotalPrice/100) * 5}}

Comment: ng-model and bind combingly not working in total price.

Comment: What exactly is `TotalPrice`? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: i have text box named "txttotalprice" ,total price = qty * unit price.my requirement is - i want to multiple qty and unit price  and show in total price col.then i have to get percentage of toal price and show in other text box called vatpercentage

Comment: Try using brackets like Paresh Gami said or try to to use ' + ' (plus) sign in front of TotalPrice to convert that to integer. I am not sure about it but it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ng-model and ng-bind like this,

`<input type="text" runat="server" ID="txttotalprice" ng-model="totalprice" ng-bind="{{totalprice= qty*unitprice }}" />`

Check this [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/h2xoob3PLPi0XgzYO71l/) for more details.

Comment: i wan to get sum of  vat amount and total amount . Text="{{qty * unitprice}} + {{(qty * unitprice/100) * 5}}" .//op-  100 + 20. but  i need 120

Comment: You can use then `<input type="text" runat="server" ID="txtVatPrice" ng-model="finalprice" ng-bind="{{qty * unitprice}} + {{(qty * unitprice/100) * 5}}" />`     check updated [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/h2xoob3PLPi0XgzYO71l/)

Answer (score 0):

```
   <tr>

                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" Text="Qty : " runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQty" Width="408px" ng-model="qty"/>
                </td>

            </tr>




            <tr>

                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" Text="Unit Price : " runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUnitPrice" Width="408px" ng-model="unitprice"/>
                </td>

            </tr>


              <tr>

                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" Text="Total Price : " runat="server"></asp:Label>

                </td>
                <td>

                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txttotalprice" Width="408px" Text="{{qty*unitprice}}"/>
                </td>

            </tr>


              <tr>

                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" Text="VAT @ 5% : " runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtVatPrice" Width="408px" Text="{{(qty*unitprice/100) * 5}}" />
                </td>

            </tr>
```